# Will my macbook air 2010 pass the airports security controls without a battery?

Tags: international-travel, electronic-items, batteries

I'm going to travel to Panama City ,and then to Barcelona ( Spain ), but i want to carry my macbook air in a backpack, the only thing that worries me is that my battery is damaged, i had to remove it and now my mac only works  plugged in. I had read that some airlines don't let pass, through the security controls, these laptops without batteries. So , is that true? what can i do then? i really need my mac.

Comment: Been on 500+ flights globally with my Macbook in my carry on backpack. No one has ever asked me to power it up. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Never had problems with any MacBook !

In any case if they ask you to power it up, you still can plug your MacBook with the adaptater.

Comment: The reason to ask you to turn on your computer is to find out that the battery is a real battery and not a bomb, so using a power adapter won't help. Opening it and showing there is no battery _should_ help, but you never know.